# Minecraft development : Where to find older Bukkit API documentation?

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

Had been stepping into Bukkit API development for a few months, most of the time I use the spigot website (https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/) to check for the APIs, last month when 1.11 released, the documentation was updated to v1.11 as well.

Due to not wanting to update the code to 1.11 at the current moment, where can I find the API documentation for Bukkit v1.10.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not aware of a site that contains the documentation for a previous version, the Maven repo for spigot does have source and documentation jars for each version that you *should* be able to attach to in your IDE.

If you want to manually set it up (or Maven refuses to work), you can manually find the jars [here](https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/bukkit/bukkit/) - first select your version, and then download the latest `-javadoc.jar` (which will be at the bottom of the page).  You can unzip that jar (which contains HTML pages rather than source or classes) and then you'll have a copy of the javadocs from that version.  In the case of 1.10.2, the jar you want is [this one](https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/bukkit/bukkit/1.10.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/bukkit-1.10.2-R0.1-20161106.012225-93-javadoc.jar).

Comment: Hi, downloaded the javadoc.jar file, it's exactly the one I want to find, greatly appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

The 1.10 version can use the 1.7.2 API to create its plugin, the 1.11 version also works.

Althought the documentation is a little different, you can refer to the latest Spigot javadocs, as nothing changed. When developing plugins for 1.7.2, one can use the Spigot 1.11 docs and there won't be any problem

---

[Latest Spigot Documentation](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/)

[Bukkit 1.7.10 Documentation](https://jd.bukkit.org/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback, due to most of the coding need to call object that exist at 1.10 version(mostly entity object), so I need that version instead of others, thanks for your help!

Comment: Usually, the code works anyway, so you can use it. Even for the Entity type

Answer (score 0):

You could download the older CraftBukkit/Spigot builds and have them generate your own copy of the HTML-javadocs.